# Reading binary (MACH-O) file load commands

Tags: c, macos, binaryfiles, otool

How does otool and similar tools read load commands? I could not find any open source tools to figure this out (even though otool is partially open source). How does it parse the binary file? Where does it start?

Thanks

Comment: Googling for "MACH-O file load" and you'll find [this Apple OS Dev page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000895) -- a concise description of the 'binary file' format, and most important its headers. *That's* where otool starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that the otool command would open the file and parse the header of the binary according to the [OSX ABI Mach-O File Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/machoruntime/Reference/reference.html)